# How does ASP.NET engine know to compile files in Areas or Controllers folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, compilation

I'm trying to add MVC to existing WebForms Web Site. I wonder, how does ASP.NET engine know that it should compile all the .cs files in Areas? Is there any configuration I should do?

I know that in Web Application Project in VS I would be able to set build action for individual files, but there is no such option in Web Site kind of VS project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC requires a Web Application project.  It cannot be added to a Web Site project.

Web Site projects have many disadvantages and quirks, and you should avoid them if at all possible.  I know, it's very convenient to be able to edit the code behinds and not have to republish, but this benefit is not worth the other disadvantages IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I understood now that these folders are handled by Visual Studio, not by webserver or engine, so if I want to make this work without project type change, I have to move the Controller folder to App_Code. It is not convinience that drives me toward Web Site -- I am afraid of the dependency on particular tooling that is enforced by sophisticated build regimes of VS. With Web Site, VS is just a great text editor.